# How To Display Arabic Text in PDFBox

Tags: java, arabic, pdfbox, right-to-left

I want to create report in Arabic using PDFBox I have saw different solution on stackoverflow but cant be get solution for my problem yet.
the arabic word came as an character in reverse order how to fix it if you have any example please help me here is my code.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

String relativeWebPath = "/font/arial.ttf";
String absoluteDiskPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
File file = new File(absoluteDiskPath);

System.out.print(file);



ByteArrayOutputStream output=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PDDocument document=new PDDocument();
PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(document, new File(absoluteDiskPath));
PDPage test=new PDPage();
document.addPage(test);
PDPageContentStream content=new PDPageContentStream(document, test);
final String EXAMPLE = "النص العربي";
System.out.print(EXAMPLE);



     content.beginText();
     content.newLineAtOffset(50, 680);
     content.setFont(font, 12);
     content.showText(EXAMPLE);
     System.out.print(EXAMPLE);
     content.endText();




 content.close();

PDFTextStripper textStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
String Text = textStripper.getText(document);
System.out.print(Text);

document.save(output);
document.close();


response.setContentType("application/pdf;base64,BASE_64_ENCODED_PDF");

response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;    filename=\"TestReport.pdf\"");
response.getCharacterEncoding();
response.getOutputStream().write(output.toByteArray());



}
```

Answer (score 0):

For support for bidirectional languages like Arabic. PDFBox uses the ICU4J library from the [International Components for Unicode](http://site.icu-project.org/) (ICU) project to support such languages in PDF documents. You need add the ICU4J jar to your project.

Comment: I have add icu4j-49_1.jar and  icu4j-charset-49_1.jar it show it as a single seprated character like  ا ب  not as a single word النص العربي.

Comment: No it doesn't use icu4j in 2.0. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2118